# Ruby closures, threads and scoping

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm trying to write a threaded Ruby application and I'm having a little trouble understanding the scoping of variables that are passed to the thread via the block.  A simplified version of the code is below

```
def threadRoutine(p1,p2)
  puts "Thread #{Thread.current.object_id} started with parameters #{p1}, #{p2}"
  Kernel.sleep 5
  puts "Thread #{Thread.current.object_id} completed"
end

start = 0
threads = []
(1..10).each do 
  finish = start + 1
  threads << Thread.new{threadRoutine(start,finish)}
  puts "Started thread #{threads[-1].object_id} with parameters #{start},#{finish}"
  start = finish
end

threads.each do |t|
  t.join
end
```

The output from this is as follows

```
Started thread 2002 with parameters 0,1
Thread 2002 started with parameters 0, 1
Started thread 2004 with parameters 1,2
Thread 2004 started with parameters 1, 2
Started thread 2006 with parameters 2,3
Thread 2006 started with parameters 3, 3
Started thread 2008 with parameters 3,4
Thread 2008 started with parameters 4, 4
Started thread 2010 with parameters 4,5
Thread 2010 started with parameters 5, 5

Thread 2010 completed
Thread 2004 completed
Thread 2002 completed
Thread 2006 completed
Thread 2008 completed
```

The first two threads start successfully with the thread starting with the same parameters as were passed from the outer routine.  Subsequent to that (thread 2006 and onwards) the p1 parameter in the thread receives the value of the 'start' variable which has been updated subsequent to the call to Thread.new

Obviously I'm misunderstanding the way things work here but I expected that the block passed to Thread.new would create a closure with the values of the variables that the block was called with.  This doesn't seem to be happening consistently.  Note that if I follow the call to Thread.new with a 1 second sleep everything works fine, but this feels like a hack and I'd like to understand how to do it properly.

Any explanations and suggestions greatly appreciated.

Here are the details of the Ruby version that I'm using

```
jruby 9.1.4.0 (2.3.1) 2016-09-01 2e1327f Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 25.51-b03 on 1.8.0_51-b16 +jit [mswin32-x86]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this chunk of code:

```
(1..10).each do 
  finish = start + 1
  threads << Thread.new{threadRoutine(start,finish)}
  puts "Started thread #{threads[-1].object_id} with parameters #{start},#{finish}"
  start = finish
end
```

The thing you have to understand is the body of `Thread.new { }` is not evaluated immediately, it's evaluated when the thread is available to run.

So, there's a race condition where multiple and/or partial iterations of this loop occur before the `Thread.new` body is evaluated. In this case, `start` and `end` will have changed in the meantime. The reason for this is that `start` is defined outside of the loop. You don't have proper closure.

To resolve this I can advise two possible solutions:

1. Define the variables *inside the iteration block, not outside it*. You're already doing this with `finish`, just need to do it with `start` as well:

   ```
   10.times do |start|
     finish = start + 1
     threads << Thread.new{threadRoutine(start,finish)}
     puts "Started thread #{threads[-1].object_id} with parameters #{start},#{finish}"
   end
   ```

   Ruby has block-level closure unless there is already a variable with the same name declared at an outer scope. Compare:

   ```
   10.times do
     a ||= 0
     a += 1
     print a
   end
   # => 1111111111

   a = 0
   10.times do
     a ||= 0
     a += 1
     print a
   end
   # => 12345678910
   ```
2. Move the `Thread.new { }` call to the method. This way you get a *method-level* closure on the variables:

   ```
   def threadRoutine(p1,p2)
     Thread.new do
       puts "Thread #{Thread.current.object_id} started with parameters #{p1}, #{p2}"
       Kernel.sleep 5
       puts "Thread #{Thread.current.object_id} completed"
     end
   end

   # later, in the loop ...
   threads << threadRoutine(start,finish)
   ```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now.  Option 1 isn't possible because in the real script the value of start is actually set using some other logic which can't go in the loop.  Option 2 is possible and it seems to be working fine.  Thanks very much